# Why is my lighting wrong?

Tags: opengl, glsl

I have a sphere centered at C(0,0,0). For now I calculate the normal inside the vertex shader. I don't pass it to it.

```
#version 330

layout(location = 0) in vec3 in_Position; //declare position
layout(location = 1) in vec3 in_Color;

// mvpmatrix is the result of multiplying the model, view, and projection matrices */
uniform mat4 MVP_matrix;

vec3 constant_col;
vec3 normal_pos,normal_light_pos;
vec3 Light_Pos = vec3(3.0f, 2.0f, 4.0f); //Light Source
float light_magn,norm_magn;
float dot_prod;
float angle;
float Light_in;

out vec3 ex_Color;

void main(void) {

// Multiply the MVP_ matrix by the vertex to obtain our final vertex position (mvp was created in *.cpp)
gl_Position = MVP_matrix * vec4(in_Position, 1.0);

//normalizing vectors 
normal_pos = normalize(in_Position);
normal_light_pos = normalize(Light_Pos);

//calculating the vector's magnitude
light_magn = sqrt(pow(normal_light_pos.x,2) + pow(normal_light_pos.y,2) + pow(normal_light_pos.z,2));
norm_magn = sqrt(pow(normal_pos.x,2) + pow(normal_pos.y,2) + pow(normal_pos.z,2));

dot_prod = dot(normal_light_pos, normal_pos); //getting the dot product
angle = dot_prod/ (light_magn*norm_magn); //getting angle in radians

angle = clamp(angle, 0, 1); 

Light_in = cos(angle); // here I calculate the light intensity

constant_col = vec3(1.0f,0.0f,0.0f); //set the sphere's color to red

ex_Color = constant_col * Light_in ; //for sphere

}
```

my code is based on Lambertian cosine rule, basically from here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambertian_reflectance

What I get is this:
[image]

Comment: Not entirely sure this will fix it, but, given the dot product is defined as the length of A * the length of B * the cosine of the angle between the vectors, and A and B in your case are 1, `dot_prod` and `Light_in` should be the same value and you can cut a bunch of computation out.

Comment: What is wrong with it specifically? Aside from the sharp highlight in the centre the rest looks ok.

Comment: There's no point "calculating" the normal in the shader. There's only one shape where one can deduce the normal from the surface points position, and that is a sphere around the origin. For every other shape the normal must be given explicitly, as you cannot determine it from the local vertex position (with some tricks you may be able to extract the facet normal in a fragment shader, but results will be poor). Just don't try calculating the normal in the shader at all. It's pointless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The scalar (=dot) product of two vectors already gives you the cosine of the angle of those vectors. So your cos(angle) is totally superfluous.

Also one normally calculates the dot product between the surface normal, and the normalized vector from light source to point on surface. You however do a dot product between light position and normal vector, which is not correct. You want something like

```
dot_prod = dot( normalize(normal_light_pos - MV * gl_Vertex, normal_pos);
```

note that the vertex is multiplied with modelview only (not modelviewprojection).

Seriously, you should work through some decent tutorial, there's just to much wrong with your attempts.

Comment: The problem was not "just the angle issue". Everyone has said it a million times by now but go read a tutorial, and some basic math and geometry ! Calculating the magnitude of a vector you've just normalized (hint: it's one. By definition.) reeks of cargo-cult programming. Also, GLSL has a length() function for this.